# Assign Axios Post to a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, ecmascript-6, axios

I want to keep reusing an axios post method across my application with changes to the `data` field. Is there a way for me to assign it to function.

My code:

```
const finalFunc = () => {
  let q_type = `query... `;
  myFunc({ query: q_type }).then((res) => res);
};

const test = (query) => {
  axios({
    url: process.env.ENDPOINT,
    method: "post",
    headers: headers,
    data: query,
  });
};

const myFunc = async (query) => {
    const result = await test(query);
    try {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 4));
    } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

finalFunc();
```

When I run this function, I am getting `ReferenceError: result is not defined` this error. I want to be able to reuse `test`. How do I do that?

Comment: You are not retuning from `test` -> `return axios ...`

Comment: When using `const` functions, scope order is important, `finalFunc` should come after `myFunc`. And yeah, `test` function is not returning value.